# How to change "if" condition related to a page

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I would like to include `tab_system.twig` file in two differents files : `archive.twig` and `blog_list.twig` to have the same html in those two files.

```
{% include "tab_system.twig" %}
```

In this `tab_system.twig` file I have a condition to add the `active` class :

`{% if XXX %}active{% endif %}`

But this condition must be different depending on which page the user is.

For `blog_list.twig` : 
`{% if loop.first %}active{% endif %}`

For `archive.twig` : 
`{% if item.term_id == term_page.term_id %}active{% endif %}`

I wrote this without success :

```
{% set addclass = '' %}

{% if is_blog_list %}
    {% set addclass = '{% if loop.first %}active{% endif %}' %}
{% elseif is_archive %}
    {% set addclass = '{% if item.term_id == term_page.term_id %}active{% endif %}' %}
{% endif %}
```

In `tab_system.twig` I have a tab system with menu from a part and content to the other part. I wrote a js loop to display the corresponding content. I need to add `active` class on the first link and first content tab in `blog_list.twig` file and to add `active` class to the link and content tab depending on which category the user is.

```
<div class="tab-menu-list">
   {% for item in all_posts %}
        <a href="#" class="tab-menu {{ addclass }}"</a>
   {% endfor %}
</div>

<div class="tab-content-list">
   {% for item in all_posts %}
        <div href="#" class="tab-content {{ addclass }}"</div>
   {% endfor %}
</div>
```

`is_archive` and `is_blog_list` are variables defined elsewhere. They work

How can I create a condition ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm assuming you are looping the records, I'd say don't overcomplicate things,

single.twig

```
{% for i in 1..5 %}
    {% include 'article.twig' with { 'active' : loop.first, } %}
{% endfor %}
```

template_blog.twig

```
{% for item in items %}
    {% include 'article.twig' with { 'active' : item.term_id == term_page.term_id, } %}
{% endfor %}
```

article.twig

```
<div class="articles__list tab-content{{ active ? ' active'}}">
    foo
</div>
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/oj2p5p) *- just change the main template*

---

If you really wanted to keep that `for` inside the `article` template, which I think is not a great idea, you could still use the variables `is_archive` and `is_blog_list` inside `article`, e.g.

article.twig

```
{% for item in items %}
    {% if is_archive %}
        {% set active = loop.first %}
    {% elseif is_blog_list %}
        {% set active = item.term_id == term_page.term_id %}
    {% endif %}
    <div class="articles__list tab-content{{ active ? ' active'}}">

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact I have my two loops in `article.twig`. I try to create a tab system. And add active class on the first loop in one file and related to an ID on an another page

Comment: Perfect ! That's work fine. I added those variables in each of my 2 loops